# How to benchmark a C program from a python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, benchmarking, timeit

I'm currently doing some work in uni that requires generating multiple benchmarks for multiple short C programs. I've written a python script to automate this process. Up until now I've been using the `time` module and essentially calculating the benchmark as such:

```
start = time.time()
successful = run_program(path)
end = time.time()

runtime = end - start
```

where the `run_program` function just uses the `subprocess` module to run the C program:

```
def run_program(path):
    p = subprocess.Popen(path, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate()[0]

    if (p.returncode > 1): 
        return False
    return True
```

However I've recently discovered that this measures elapsed time and not CPU time, i.e. this sort of measurement is sensitive to noise from the OS. Similar questions on SO suggest that the `timeit` module is is better for measuring CPU time, so I've adapted the run method as such:

```
def run_program(path):
    command = 'p = subprocess.Popen(\'time ' + path + '\', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE); out, err = p.communicate()'

    result = timeit.Timer(command, setup='import subprocess').repeat(1, 10)
    return numpy.median(result)
```

But from looking at the `timeit` documentation it seems that the `timeit` module is only meant for small snippets of python code passed in as a string. So I'm not sure if `timeit` is giving me accurate results for this computation. So my question is: Will `timeit` measure the CPU for every step of the process that it runs or will it only measure the CPU time for the actual python(i.e. the `subprocess` module) code to run? Is this an accurate way to benchmark a set of C programs?

Comment: An executable contains machine code, not C code. The C tag is completely irrelevant.

Comment: The `time` shell builtin looks like a good option.  On Linux, you can also use `perf stat some_program` to get performance counter counts for instructions, clock cycles, cache misses, and branch mispredicts (or any other set of counters, those are just the defaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeit` will measure the CPU time used by the Python process in which it runs. Execution time of external processes will not be "credited" to those times.

Answer (score -1):

A more accurate way would be to do it in C, where you can get true speed and throughput.

Comment: That's my backup option; Write a c program that times and runs the code, and use subprocess to call that from my python script. Seemed a bit messy at first but it's looking like that's the way to go!